# Hebrew Ben Chayyim Second Rabbinic Bible is missing Joshua 6:9 to 7:1

Tags: hebrew

I have a copy of the Hebrew Ben Chayyim Second Rabbinic Bible which was scanned and in the book of Joshua it is missing Joshua 6:9 to 7:1.

It is obviously a mistake and not intentional because the chapter numbers carry on as normal.
The text should be between pages number 18 and 19.

Is there another edition/copy available online of the Ben Chayyim 2nd Rabbinic Bible where this was printed correctly?

[image: Page 18 of Joshua]

[image: Page 19 of Joshua]

Comment: This would make a better fit on [Judaism.SE](http://judaism.stackexchange.com). Also, just because the verse numbering follows the traditional scheme does not mean that the omission of the verses in between was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there are two pages missing in between pages 18 and 19 in that copy, namely, pg. 242b & 244c in the copy at archive.org(columns a,b,c,d reading right to left).

As it appears, the latter of which I referenced appears to be a 1545 edition of the former.

Comment: Could you provide a link or reference to what you record ?

Comment: The missing pages are [here](https://archive.org/details/The_Second_Rabbinic_Bible_Vol_2/page/n16/mode/1up) but I don't see the pagination you refer too. I see 31a at the bottom of the page